# Qual è il significato di "lasco" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, adjectives

Nel romanzo *Rossovermiglio* di Benedetta Cibrario ho letto:

> Sellavo il cavallo e andavo, lo lasciavo correre fino a sfiancarlo il mio mezzosangue giù dalla querceta, a rotta di collo, rischiando la scivolata, l'incidente, cercando il pericolo; a volte arrivavo addirittura a lasciare **lasco** il sottopancia; cosa cercassi, non lo so; che Trott e il mondo intero stessero in pena per me, forse; e magari che a qualcuno importasse, che so, di dove stavo andando, di cosa facevo.

Non capisco il senso dell'aggettivo "lasco" in questo brano. Ho cercato il [significato di "lasco" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/lasco/), ma tutte le accezioni che ho trovato non sembrano avere senso in questo contesto. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "lasciare lasco il sottopancia del cavallo"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il [sottopancia](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sottopancia/) è la cinghia che tiene ferma la sella, stretta attorno all'addome del cavallo.

Lasciarlo *lasco*, cioè non ben stretto, allentato, è molto rischioso.